# Show that $\mathrm{d}S=\frac{1}{T}\,\mathrm{d}U+\frac{1}{T}\,P\,\mathrm{d}V-\frac{1}{T}\,\mu\,\mathrm{d}N$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy, chemical-potential

I need help to show that \begin{align*}\mathrm{d}S &=\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}\right)_{V,N}\mathrm{d}U+\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_{U,N}\mathrm{d}V+\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial N}\right)_{V,U}dN\tag{1}\\&=\frac{1}{T}\mathrm{d}U+\frac{1}{T}P\mathrm{d}V-\frac{1}{T}\mu\mathrm{d}N\tag{2}\end{align*}

where $U$ is the Internal Energy of the system; $S$ is the Entropy of the system; $N$ is the Number of Particles in the system; $V$ is the Volume of the system; $P$ is the systems' Pressure; $T$ is the absolute (thermodynamic) temperature of the system and $\mu$ is the Chemical Potential of the system.

I know that the coefficients of $\mathrm{d}U$,$\,\mathrm{d}V$ and $\mathrm{d}N$ must match for equations $(1)$ and $(2)$ ie.
$$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}\right)_{V,N}=\frac{1}{T}\tag{A}$$
$$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_{U,N}=\frac{1}{T}P\tag{B}$$
$$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial N}\right)_{V,U}=-\frac{1}{T}\mu\tag{C}$$

But I simply have no idea how to show $(\mathrm{A})$, $(\mathrm{B})$ and $(\mathrm{C})$. So this means I am stuck at the *very beginning* and hence cannot show my attempt at providing a solution (reason for question closure).

---

For context I have added the pages of my text that *shows* the equivalence of equations $(1)$ and $(2)$:

[image: Chemical Equilibria 1]
[image: Chemical Equilibria 2]
[image: Chemical Equilibria 3]
[image: Chemical Equilibria 4]

---

Could someone please help me show that

\begin{align*}&\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}\right)_{V,N}\mathrm{d}U+\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_{U,N}\mathrm{d}V+\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial N}\right)_{V,U}dN\\&=\frac{1}{T}\mathrm{d}U+\frac{1}{T}P\mathrm{d}V-\frac{1}{T}\mu\mathrm{d}N\end{align*}

Any hints or tips are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I recently read that the S really is an implicit function or something, I think $S(U(V,N,T),V(U,N,T), N(U,V,T))$ maybe ?

Comment: @Emil Okay, thanks for your response. That being the case how can I use that information to show that $$\begin{align*}&\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}\right)_{V,N}\mathrm{d}U+\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_{U,N}\mathrm{d}V+\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial N}\right)_{V,U}dN\\&=\frac{1}{T}\mathrm{d}U+\frac{1}{T}P\mathrm{d}V-\frac{1}{T}\mu\mathrm{d}N\end{align*}$$

Comment: Don't know... but I think it will be more clear if you write it out. I tried to write the differential but I think I made a mistake... If I remember correct $dS = \partial_U (S)\cdot (dV\partial_V + dN\partial_N + dT\partial_T)(U)+ \ldots$ (i.e. chain rule)

Comment: Thanks for your help @Emil but unfortunately I still have no idea what to do. It seems there is something really simple I am missing here, as the author of the extract I posted showed no intermediate steps whatsoever to get from $$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}\right)_{V,N}\mathrm{d}U+\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_{U,N}\mathrm{d}V+\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial N}\right)_{V,U}dN$$ to $$=\frac{1}{T}\mathrm{d}U+\frac{1}{T}P\mathrm{d}V-\frac{1}{T}\mu\mathrm{d}N$$

Comment: Oh and another thing, in thermodynamics they usually assume that second derivatives taken in different order are the same ($\partial_U\partial_V f = \partial_V\partial_U f$). Oh and they usually assume some form for the laws of thermodynamics. Perhaps they used one of the laws there? $dU=TdS + other stuff$?

Comment: @Emil Yes, thanks because the equations of state require that the differentials are exact and exactness requires $$\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 U}{{\partial y}{\partial x}}$$

Comment: The point in the text would be moot then though.. Ok so $dS=\partial_U(S)\cdot (dV\partial_V + dN \partial_N +  dT \partial_T)(U) + \partial_V(S)\cdot (dU\partial_U + dN \partial_N +  dT \partial_T)(V) + \partial_N(S)\cdot (dV\partial_V + dU \partial_U +  dT \partial_T)(N)$. To me it seems that they say $dU(\partial_V(S)\partial_U(V)+\partial_N(S)\partial_U(N))=dU T^{-1}$. No idea why. I think something about invariants and integrable factors are related to T.

Comment: It might be that their differentials mean something like this too: dU=d(U(V,N)) and they don't expand it like I did (perhaps I should have used a tilde on the functions). In that case they say $\partial_{\tilde U}(S)d\tilde U=\partial_{\tilde U}(S)(dV\partial_V+dN\partial_N + dT\partial_T)(\tilde U)=T^{-1}d\tilde U$ and so on.. which kind of fits in with their $\mu$ I guess $\partial_{\tilde N}(S)d\tilde N=-\mu/T d\tilde N$ as they defined it but still looks weird to me.

Comment: Have they defined $P/Td\tilde V=\partial_{\tilde V}(S)d\tilde V$ and $1/T d\tilde U=\partial_{\tilde U}(S) d\tilde U$ somewhere? In that case it was just substitution.

Comment: Ah. They just chose coefficents in terms of 1/T. Like $dS=adU+bdV+cdN$ with $a=1/T, b=Pa, c=-\mu a$. Unless they have provided definition of P somewhere else that contradicts this.

Comment: Unless you add the definitions of $T,P$ and $\mu$, this question is unanswerable because many people might take your eqs. (A),(B),(C) as *definitions* of these quantitites so there's nothing to show.

Comment: Oh, I might have missed something, perhaps $S=S(\tilde U(U, V, N, T), \tilde V(U, V, N, T), \tilde N(U, V, N, T), \tilde T(U, V, N, T))$. Let's hope someone with more experience than me drops by.

Comment: Are you allowed to start out with $dU=TdS-PdV+\mu dN$?

Comment: I'll just add that the triple product rule (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product_rule) comes in handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}\right)_{V,N}=\frac{1}{T}\tag{A}$$

Is **defined** as an expression for temperature and is **not** derived.
Once they teach you entropy, they **use** it to tighten the definition of temperature.

$$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}\right)_{U,N}=\frac{1}{T}P\tag{B}$$

is also introduced by reasoned argument, as the imposed  **definition** of pressure, (when you get the $P$  on its own),  rather than any derivation and I am inclined to believe this is because it might involve a Legrande transformation, which would take to long to explain,  as well being slightly off-topic.

$$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial N}\right)_{V,U}=\frac{1}{T}\mu\tag{C}$$

The final expression involves extending the thermodynamic equation to include "chemical work" and you get it by

$$\mathrm{d}U= T\mathrm{d}S -P\mathrm{d}V + \mu \mathrm{d}N$$

Now $U, S, V, N $  are all capable of change in the above  equation.

So imagine we hold the variables  $U,S $ fixed

Such that $$0 = T\mathrm{d}S + \mu \mathrm{d}N$$

leads to $$ \mu = -T \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial N}\right)_{V,U}$$

which leads to $$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial N}\right)_{V,U}=-\frac{1}{T}\mu\tag{C}$$

Comment: I looked through 3 different thermal physics books, and all of them avoided explicity deriving them, relying instead on **trust me** reasoned arguments plus there is/was a reference to them being definitions in the comments, so......

Comment: Thank you so much for excellent answer and sorry it took me so long to reply. Ever since, I read your answer I have been searching books and online for some evidence of $(A)$ (which I discovered to be linked to the thermodynamic beta without the Boltzmann constant) and $(B)$ found here: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/therid.html. It was also brought to my attention that $(C)$ has already been defined in the extract I posted in my question and I also found it here: http://theory.physics.manchester.ac.uk/~judith/stat_therm/node61.html where there is a .....

Comment: link that defines $(A)$, $(B)$ and $(C)$, but I don't agree with it. Sorry the comment formatting came out wrong before, apologies.

Comment: I lack the rep myself, so I can't help you on the reopen. Homework type = homework...... got caught on that one myself.  From the comments and the initial $\Delta T$ inclusion,  confusion resulted and "no effort" because of the copied pages, which I would avoid.  No offence, but I would have thought the same.  Please don't take this the wrong way.... The golden rule of this site is.......learn and move on, best of luck with your next question.

Comment: Understood, thanks for your advice, it sure does operate differently here to MSE. Regards.